# Easy way to develop Mozilla Firefox extension from Google Chrome extension

Tags: html, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, xul

I 've developed a simple application for Google Chrome extension, first the interface created using HTML and CSS, and then the action created using JavaScript and PHP.

Then I want to develop the application for the Mozilla Firefox, which of the references that I read using XUL and CSS development for interface, and actions using JavaScript.

The question is, could I develop Mozilla Firefox extension using a language that I use when I develop Google Chrome extensions (interface with HTML and CSS, and action using JavaScript and PHP)?

If not, is there any application that can use to facilitate the development of Mozilla Firefox extensions? Considering I've been using **XUL Exploreler**, and it still was not helpful.

**notes:** 
*Description of the application that I developed, there are forms which user must fill, and time the user presses the button the JavaScript will work and contact PHP to access MySQL database.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a multi-browser extension, I strongly advise you to stay away from XUL as much as possible. For example, if you need to get data from the user, use the same HTML for that you are using in Chrome. If necessary you can embed a  element in a XUL panel in order to display your HTML, but in most cases you can probably just display it in a browser window/tab (which is presumably what you are doing in Chrome).

Comment: I just read a reference to embed HTML elements in XUL, like this whether you mean?
`<html:p>
  <html:input id="rtd" type="checkbox"/>
  <html:label for="rtd">Remember This Decision</html:label>
</html:p>`
If so, it means I have to change all HTML tags from the previous application by adding "html:" in every beginning tag, and "/html:" at each end of the tag. And I have thousands of lines of HTML tags. It will wasting my time.
_Are there other ways such as displaying a small browser window popup like in Google Chrome, so I do not need to change all the HTML tags that I have?_

Comment: Well normally you would say (assuming a XUL overlay): `<overlay id="my-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` meaning that XUL is the default namespace but you could also say `<overlay id="my-overlay" xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` so that HTML is the default namespace and prefix all the XUL tags with `xul:`.